# Change url of language on Qtranslate-x

Tags: wordpress, lang, qtranslate-x

I need to change the language url from /en/ to /eng/ using the plugin qtranslate-x.
I try to change the language code but i can insert only max 2 characters.

Comment: This is probably not possible without hacking the plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is true, and if you want to do - you have to make a very big hack. Almost rewrite plugin.